# What does $F$ in the equation of surface tension $(T=\frac{F}l)$ mean?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, surface-tension

As far as I knew or assumed: If an imaginary line is thought to be present on a surface, then molecules of the surface will attract or exert equal forces throughout the length of the Line. So in a nutshell let say the centre of mass or the centre of the line faces a force equal to $F$ on one side, so unit length of the line will face $\frac{F} l$ amount of force and by definition this is supposed to be the surface tension (force per unit length). The line is supposed to be static so it faces equal force on the opposite side but tension is same throught surface, hence it wouldn't change anything I presume.

If the concept I mentioned is correct,then what does $F$ stand for the equation of surface tension of a ring? I mean in case of line I could say that equal small forces sum upto a larger force acting on one side of tha centre of the line, perpendicular to the line. And those smaller forces are actually the tension. But can we assume the same thing for a ring or a disc? I am asking this question because of not being able to visualize the same thing for a curvature. Could it be that this time tension equals to the ratio of net force acting on a small straight linear fragment of circumference to the lenght of that fragment? But I have seen in some textbooks for discs tension is considered to be equal to the ratio of force and the circumference which for me didn't make any sense at all.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/670586/how-does-the-soap-bubble-film-expansion-phenomenon-gives-us-an-idea-that-numeric

Answer (score 0):

For a disc or ring

> this time tension equals to the ratio of net force acting on a small straight linear fragment of circumference to the length of that fragment

seems like a reasonable definition.

It's true that the total force has no resultant direction, but it's often the case that energy is used to deal with such problems - i.e the energy needed to expand the ring from radius $r$ to $r+\delta r$ would be (from force x distance)

$$E= T\times 2 \pi r\times \delta r$$

Some textbooks would use the above concept to define the magnitude of the net force for a disc, hence define surface tension as the ratio of the 'net force' and the circumference.

Comment: But to derive the equation of energy  we are more or less dependent on the equation of surface tension. So aren't we back to the same problem?

Comment: @ MSK the formula is about the work done expanding the circle, e.g. increasing the circular area of a soap bubble, since the work done by the force and the change in radius are in the same direction, the work done is positive for each small section, even though the forces are pointing in opposite directions on opposite sides of the circle.

Comment: Does $F=2\pi rT$ for disc basically mean that $F$ is the sumtotal of magnitude of equal forces acting allover the circumference of the disc?